# HTML tag placeholder using JS

Tags: javascript, html

For the following HTML input tag:

```
<input id="search_bar" type="text" placeholder="search...">
```

I replace placeholder value with empty content using JS as below:

```
document.getElementById("search_bar").addEventListener("click", function(){
            document.getElementById("search_bar").placeholder = "";
    });
```

However, I am not able to revert the change back when clicking else where outside input tag. how can I replace the original placeholder value "search..." as it was before??

Comment: store before the content of document.getElementById("search_bar").placeholder e.g. in a variable and restore that

Comment: You can utilize `.focusout()` method to set the place holder again if the input value is still blank.  https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_focusout.asp

Comment: there's... literally no reason to do this. You're recreating the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `blur` event.

As a plus, my solution queries the DOM only once, and handling the `focus` event rather than `click` also hides the placeholder if you tab into the field:

```
var txt = document.getElementById("search_bar")
txt.addEventListener("focus", function(){
        this.placeholder = "";
});
txt.addEventListener("blur", function(){
        this.placeholder = "search...";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally with something this basic I would just add another event listener for the "blur event" as such:

```
<input id="search_bar" type="text" placeholder="search..." >

document.getElementById("search_bar").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("search_bar").placeholder = "";
});

document.getElementById("search_bar").addEventListener("blur", function(){
  document.getElementById("search_bar").placeholder = "search...";
});
```

That did the trick for me when trying it out in a Codepen.

Answer (score 0):

Change the event from click to focus

```
document.getElementById("search_bar").addEventListener("focus", function(){
            document.getElementById("search_bar").placeholder = "";
    });
```

Then set it back on blur event

```
document.getElementById("search_bar").addEventListener("blur", function(){
            document.getElementById("search_bar").placeholder = "Search...";
    });
```

However, I don't think this is necessary because by default, the placeholder is removed when user starts typing